# Flutter "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps"

Tags: flutter, dart

Basically I want to return to my LoginView when the user presses Logout in the dialog.

```
onSelected: (value) async {
              switch (value) {
                case MenuAction.logout:
                  final shouldLogout = await showLogOutDialog(context);
                  final navigator = Navigator.of(context);
                  if (shouldLogout) {
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                    navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      '/login',
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  }
              }
            },
```

showLogoutDialog function:

```
Future<bool> showLogOutDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Sign out'),
        content: const Text('Are you sure you want to sign out?'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: const Text('Logout'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ).then((value) => value ?? false);
```

I get this error: "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps.".
[image: Error at Navigator.of(contex]

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some answers I found told me to just place the final navigator = Navigator.of(context) above the final shoulLogout and it seemed to work, but then others said it wasn't the right way to do it. Because  it hides the related analyzer warning, it is only a bug in the analyzer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is unsafe, try checking if the widget is not mounted as shown on the [Flutter YouTube Channel](https://youtu.be/bzWaMpD1LHY).

```dart
if (!mounted) return
Navigator.of(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after an `await`, every use of the `BuildContext` will show this warning. This warning happens because using a `BuildContext` after an `await` could happen after the widget is disposed of. This way, the context wouldn't exist anymore, and the app could even crash because of it. Check out [the official link to documentation](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/use_build_context_synchronously.html):

> Storing BuildContext for later usage can easily lead to difficult-to-diagnose crashes. Asynchronous gaps are implicitly storing BuildContext and are some of the easiest to overlook when writing code.

The easy solution, from the official documents, is the need to check for [`State.mounted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html). The code would look something like this on every place the warning shows up:

```dart
      ...
      } else {
        if (mounted) Navigator.of(context);
      }
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you Kasun for this detailed information

Comment: Welcome @DJFreeman. But using word like your first two words can lead violviolation of stackoverflow guidlines